# Sanitizing JSON deserialization

Tags: java, owasp, json

I'm currently investigating best practices for secure JSON deserialization of untrusted input for object mapping. After researching, it seems like...

the default jackson mapper:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45846083/using-jackson-java-to-ensure-that-and-all-serialization-to-json-delimits-untrust

and OWASP JSON sanitizer
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_JSON_Sanitizer

...both accomplish what I'm looking for. From a security perspective, is there a reason to use the OWASP JSON sanitizer if we're already using jackson objectmapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the NCC group's [Jackson Deserialization Vulnerabilities](https://www.nccgroup.trust/globalassets/our-research/us/whitepapers/2018/jackson_deserialization.pdf):

> Jackson does not perform typing by default (including collection generic
>   types) and does not allow the specification of arbitrary types

Besides the link you gave, OWASP has a page on the [Deserialization of untrusted data](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Deserialization_of_untrusted_data) which explains how to handle types.